# C# Transform a point from one screen coordinate to another screen coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, transform, coordinate-systems

I have a point in `320*240` coordinate system and I want to transform to different coordinate system say to `1024*768` or `1920*1600`.

*Is there a predefined `.net` classes to achieve this?*

I am trying to solve it like this -

```
screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
double newWidth = x / 320 * screenWidth;
double newHeight = y / 240 * screenHeight;
bola.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newWidth);
bola.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newHeight);
```

I am getting a point from `320*240` coordinate system and I am trying to move it to another coordinate system.

*Is there a better way to achieve this?*

Secondly I am keep on getting this points, Is there a better way to smooth this, as its very jittery in movement?

Thanks

Comment: If x and y are integers, x / 320 as well as y / 240 are both integer divisions and that's why result could be wrong: e.g. for x = 300 you'll have 0. If it's your case rewrite the formula: double newWidth = x / 320.0 * screenWidth and double newHeight = y / 240.0 * screenHeight

Comment: everything is in double here.

Comment: Have a look at Matrix.Transform:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607598.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the origin in both systems of reference is identical, what is the case (0, 0); the only thing you can do is scaling the values from one to the other system by relying on a simple rule of three:

```
curX    -> in 340
newX    -> in newWidth(1024)

newX = newWidth(1024) * curX/340 OR newX = curX * ratio_newWidthToOldWidth
```

Same for height (`newY = curY * ratio_newHeightToOldHeight`).

This is already a pretty simple way so why looking for simpler alternatives?

In any case, you should bear in mind that the width/height ratio change from one resolution to the other (i.e., 1.33 and 1.2 in the examples you provide) and thus if you apply this conversion blindly the appearance of the objects might change (would be adapted to the given screen but perhaps would look worse than what you want). Thus you might want to mantain the original width-to-height ratio and do something like:

```
newX = ...
newY = ...
if(newX / newY != origXYRatio)
{
   newX = newY * origXYRatio // or vice versa
}
```

Thus, in this case, you would just need to calculate one variable, X or Y.

Answer (score 0):

You're transforming your co-ordinates from some virtual system (i.e. 320x240) to a real co-ordinate system (i.e. `PrimaryScreenWidth`x`PrimaryScreenHeight`).  I don't think there's a better way to do that other than what you're doing.

To improve code readability, you might introduce a function to better communicate what you're up to:

```
// Or whatever the type of "ctl" is ...
private void SetPositionInVirtualCoords(Control ctl, double x, double y)
{
    screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;        
    ctl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x * (screenWidth/320.0));
    ctl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y * (screenHeight/240.0));
}
```

... so that your main code can read as:

```
SetPositionInVirtualCoords(bola, x, y);
```

and can be re-used by other controls as well.